# Removing an attached application from ConEmu/undoing "Attach to..."

Tags: python, conemu, atom-editor

I just started using ConEmu as I liked the tabbed feature (sometimes I hate having a python CLI and CMD and R and git and whatever else all open in their own windows - gets tricky to immediately identify what's what). I use Atom as my general editor, and in playing around with ConEmu, I attached my currently-open instance of Atom to ConEmu -- which, of course, 'closed' the separate Atom instance and stuck it in a ConEmu tab.

I decided I'd prefer to keep Atom and ConEmu separate, though, but I can't find a way to 'undo' that attachment (move the 'atom' tab back to its own native application/window) without saving everything, closing the tab, opening atom directly, and re-opening everything I had open. There were several tabs open in atom containing random code I didn't intend on keeping around after I finish what I'm working on. Searching stackexchange and the ConEmu docs was fruitless, and none of the menu options I can find in ConEmu suggest a way to do this.

While I realize that yes, I *could* just save all the random crap as separate files, close the ConEmu Atom tab, and reopen everything in Atom proper, it seems like there should be some way of doing this while preserving the files I already have open in their current state. I also don't want to lose the undo  chains on the 'real' scripts I was working on.

Am I really stuck either sifting through the open files in Atom to make sure I don't need the undo history and then saving+reopening in Atom again or completing the projects within ConEmu, or is there a way to transfer Atom (in its current, ConEmu-wrapped state) back to a proper Atom window?

Comment: As for me, I didn't understand anything. Perhaps screenshots could clarify your problem

Comment: Oops, sorry, I forgot to delete the post. I ended up uninstalling ConEmu after a coworker showed me MobaXterm which (for my purposes) seems far superior.

Thank you for the attempt at helping, though!

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, though, and ConEmu is actually what I want. To avoid cluttering up the boards, feel free to reach out via the contact info in my profile and I can show you what I was talking about in the OP. I didn't realize you were the ConEmu author :)